# How to calaculate thresh value for different images to pass into houghlines functions?

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

```
rho, theta, thresh = 1, 1 * np.pi / 180, 250

lines = cv2.HoughLines(hed_binary, rho, theta, thresh)
```

how to calculate this threshold value we pass in HoughLines function for different images?

Comment: this would depend your images and the lines you want to find. do you even know what this threshold does or how HT works? there is no magic formula.

Comment: the minimum number of votes depends on the number of rho-theta bins, your resolution, the line length and your line quality preferences, the number of lines you want to find... many many things, most of them you decide. do you want to find lines 10 points contribute to or 500? that's 100% up to you and your usecase